# clear all messages sent by the bot in dm

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**hello stackoverflow i need help on discord.py i want to clear all messages sent by the bot to some or all good someone used my bot to do this and i need to clear it so he doesn't get banned from discord you can help me?**

```python
@bot.event
async def on_ready(member):
    dmchannel = await member.create_dm()
    async for message in dmchannel.history(limit=50): 
        if message.author == bot.user:
            await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

**The on_ready event doesn't take member as an argument.**

The on_ready event is called when the bot is loaded. It is not possible to get DMS using discord.py but you can get all DMS using [Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference) and [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

Code:

```
import requests # pip install requests

your_bot_id = "<your bot's id>"
token = '<your token>'
message_limit = 50


headers = {
  "Authorization" : f"Bot {token}"
}

url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/channels"
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
channels = resp.json()

for channel in channels:
    ch_id = channel['id']
    ch_url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{ch_id}/messages?limit={message_limit}"
    resp2 = requests.get(ch_url, headers=headers)
    messages = resp2.json()

    for message in messages:
        if message['author']['id'] == your_bot_id:
             remove_url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{ch_id}/messages/{message['id']}"
             remove_resp = requests.delete(remove_url, headers=headers)
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: jiw thank but that already makes me have to finish this code?

Comment: No. Just add your token and bot's id.

Comment: not work for me

Comment: What exacly is not working?

Comment: this code it just skips a line in cmd or turns it on and off

Comment: Like this code isn't printing anything so it shouldn't show anything.

Comment: I sent a message on my private dm and it doesn't delete

Comment: Yea, I checked it and for some reason this doesn't work on bots.. So the channels returns empty list.

Comment: What should I do?